# What are the biggest events to follow for the most competitive decks in Magic the Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Obviously I would be following the Grand Prix, Pro Tours and World Championships that are hosted by Wizards of the Coast. I'm assuming events hosted by Star City Games are worth following too (do they provide deck lists)?

What are the big events that provide deck lists that I should be following to be the most up to date on Standard decks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that TCGPlayer.com includes decklists from StarCityGames (SCG) and larger MTGO tournaments, they are my go-to site for decklists. [Here](http://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?page=1&format=standard&latestset=hour-of-devastation&p1=true&p2=true) is a search for the number 1 and 2 decks from all of the recent major Standard tournaments.

In case the link rots, you can go to TCGPlayer.com, click on "Magic Decks", and search for the winning decks from major events. Right now it looks like they include:

- Grand Prixs
- Pro Tours
- Pro Tour Qualifiers (including those on MTGO)
- Magic Online Championship Series (MOCS)
- SCG Classic/SCG Open

You can also view the MOCS decklists directly on the Wizards of the Coast website. The search functionality is pretty buggy. Searching for Standard format will yield no results in over two years. However, you can [search for "Standard MOCS" without quotes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info) to get at the more recent results.

StarCityGames.com also hosts their own decklists, which you can find [here](https://www.starcitygames.com/content/decklists/).

Comment: Is there a way to get the Magic Online Championship Series decks directly from Wizards of the Coast?

Comment: @rotaercz I think I figured it out, and I updated the answer. It took me a few minutes to figure out because the search on the WotC website is buggy.